# Focus image does not work for first time on Textbox

Tags: wpf, textbox, focus, styles, focusvisualstyle

i want to show a focus image around a text box when it got focus. so i create following style

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxFocusVisualStyle">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Image Source="/WPFApp;component/Resources/txtFocus.png"  Stretch="Fill"  Margin="-8,-6,-8,-6"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

and in window xaml file i used this style as following

```
<TextBox  Grid.Column="1" Height="34" Margin="186,48,0,0" Name="txtEmailId" VerticalAlignment="Top" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="0" MaxWidth="293" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="293" Text="" FocusVisualStyle="{DynamicResource TextBoxFocusVisualStyle}"/>
```

but problem is that it does not work during loading. When window load then initially focus is on that textbox and at that time it does not show the image .However when i navigate to other textbox (and other control) then it show focus image. and finally when i focus return to that textbox then it display the focus image

so problem is that it does not show focus image first time on when window loaded. Please suggest that where i am wrong.

Comment: Perhaps you can take a look on msdn for the default style of the textbox and check wether the focus visual style is connected to the focus event or the isfocused property.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that FocusVisualStyle applies to a control only when focused by keyboard (TAB key).

This is different from the logical focus that you obtain for example using

```
 Control.SetFocus()
```

For an overview on Focus have a look at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768.aspx

A possible workaround for your problem is work with DependencyProperty IsFocused an use Style instead of FocusVisualStyle

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Image  Stretch="Fill"  Margin="-8,-6,-8,-6" Source="/WPFApp;component/Resources/txtFocus.png" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

And then in the main Window

```
<TextBox  Grid.Column="1" Height="34" Margin="186,48,0,0" Name="txtEmailId" 
     VerticalAlignment="Top" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="0" MaxWidth="293" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="293" Text="" 
                  Style="{DynamicResource TextBoxFocusVisualStyle}" Background="White" />
```

Hope this heps

Comment: now focus image is displayed but textbox does not appear even i set background property to white color

Comment: Right, perhaps this could help

<ControlTemplate>
<Grid>
   <Image  Stretch="Fill"  Margin="-8,-6,-8,-6" Source="/WPFApp;component/Resources/txtFocus.png" />

 <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
  </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

Comment: sorry for late reply. above code works but in this case font size is too small and cursor is not displayed

Comment: Try to replace the textbox in the ControlTemplate with <ScrollViewer Margin="2" Name="PART_ContentHost" Background="White" >