# Textbox focus does not work when focus by mouseclick wpf

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, textbox, wpf-controls, focus

When I click on text box by mouse then focus does not display. and when I goes to textbox by keyboard then focus displayed. I am trying below code. So please can any one suggest me how I solve this issue.

```
 <Style x:Key="TextBoxFocusVisualStyle" >
     <Setter Property="Control.Template">
          <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate>
                        <Image Source="/Mit;component/Resources/txtFocus.png"  Stretch="Fill"  Margin="-8,-6,-8,-6"/>
               </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
 </Style>

<TextBox  Grid.Column="2" Height="44" Margin="20,48,0,0" Name="txtEmailId" VerticalAlignment="Top" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" MaxWidth="400" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="350" Text=""  FocusVisualStyle="{DynamicResource TextBoxFocusVisualStyle}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="18" ContextMenu="{x:Null}" />
```

I also tried below code after @hattenn answer:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>



        <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <VisualBrush>
                                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Image Source="/WpfApplication1;component/Resources/txtFocus.png"  Stretch="Fill"  Margin="-8,-6,-8,-6"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </VisualBrush.Visual>
                            </VisualBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>


    </Application.Resources>
```

and

```
<TextBox Height="23" Name="textBox1" Width="120" Focusable="True" FocusVisualStyle="{DynamicResource TextBoxStyle}"/>
```

But it does not work for me. nothing happened. please suggest.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`FocusVisualStyle` is only for keyboard focus, you can check it out here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.focusvisualstyle.aspx

For general focus, you can use the `IsFocused` property, more info below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isfocused.aspx

As an example, you can try something like this:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <VisualBrush>
                        <VisualBrush.Visual>
                            <Grid>
                                <Image Source="/Mit;component/Resources/txtFocus.png"  Stretch="Fill"  Margin="-8,-6,-8,-6"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </VisualBrush.Visual>
                    </VisualBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: I tried this. but its not working for me. no error but no any effects. any idea?

Comment: Well I tried it and it was working perfectly. Couple ideas: 1) Is there any other style that affects the `TextBox`? 2) Are you using the correct key name? In your example, your key name is `TextBoxFocusVisualStyle`, in this example the key name is `TextBoxStyle`. Check these out but this example is definitely working, there's probably something interfering in your code with this style.

Comment: As I have already written, what you are looking for is not `FocusVisualStyle`, it is the first sentence in my answer. You are setting the `FocusVisualStyle` which is only applicable for *keyboard focus*. You are supposed to set the style of your textbox, which has a trigger to change the background when the `IsFocused` property of your textbox is set to `true`, which happens both when it is keyboard focused or mouse focused. To put it simply, you need to do this: `<TextBox Height="23" Name="textBox1" Width="120" Focusable="True" Style="{DynamicResource TextBoxStyle}"/>`

Comment: I already tried the style but when using style property background of text is not displayed even I set the background=white and cursor is not visible in textbox. please suggest.


Similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680343/focus-image-does-not-work-for-first-time-on-textbox

Comment: Well the problem is obvious, you can't set the background twice. You are setting the background as an image, you cannot set it to white at the same time. One way to do what you want is to create a custom control deriving from `TextBox`, which will have a separate dependency property with a name like `ImageSource` and an `Image` inside it's template. So you can set the `Background` as white, and set the `ImageSource` in the trigger to whatever image you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just add style to Textbox:

```
position:relative;
```

Comment: Going for the archaeology badge?